# How do I get Visual Studio 2017 Evaluation to recognize .NET Framework 4.6.2 installed?

Tags: asp.net, installation, visual-studio-2017, .net-4.6.2

1) I did a clean install of Visual Studio 2017 Professional Evaluation copy on a brand new Dell laptop. 
2) I tried to import and open a project solution which had been running on another computer with Visual Studio 2015 Professional full copy.  Both computers run on Windows 10 Professional and fully updated.
3) Received error from Visual Studio upon solution import which said I could not load the project unless I changed the target of the.NET framework from 4.6.2 to .NET 4.6.1. because the 4.6.2 was not found on my machine.
4) Verified that 4.6.2 was in the registry
5) Tried to download a fresh install of 4.6.2 but it would not install because it also found 4.6.2 on the machine.
6) I also tried to load the project as 4.6.1 and then go in via the properties to change the target to 4.6.2 but had the same results.

Any suggestions as to how I can either get Visual Studio 2017 to recognize the 4.6.2 or uninstall 4.6.2 and reinstall?[image: registry entry for .NET framework 4.6.2]

Comment: You Open Your Project in new Project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Runtime version and Target versions are different things. You need to run `Visual Studio 2017 setup` and select `.net 4.6.2 SDK/Targeting pack` under `Individual Components`:

[image]

They are not selected by default in VS2017. You have to do this for .net 4.7 as well, this is also not installed by default.

Comment: This answer worked beautifully for me. It might help others to know that my initial install screen looked a little different because the Summary on the right didn't show the 4.6.2 option.  So I had to look further into the Individual Components tab to actually get to select the right option.  Then once it was selected it showed up in the summary.

Comment: yes, this screenshot is from older preview. I didn't want to start new installer on my system

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install the .NetFramework 4.6.2 Developer pack.(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321)

Comment: this is for VS2012, VS2013, VS2015 to target .net 4.6.2, he wants it for VS2017

Comment: I know, I had this issue when I installed VS17 and that was how I fixed it.

Comment: no, run installer and add select the correct .net 4.6.2 entry. only 4.6.1 is enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

Check here. In effect, you need install .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack

https://superuser.com/questions/1254177/visual-studio-doesnt-recognize-net-framework-4-6-2-is-installed